Probability the room is vacant

Your workplace has a phone room for employees to quietly make personal calls. The room has no windows, just a sign that can be switched from “Vacant” to “Occupied”. However, employees differ in how consistently they use the sign:

1/2 of them always switch to “Occupied” when they enter and “Vacant” when they exit.
1/4 of them ignore the sign altogether – the sign will always read the same before, during, and after their visit.
1/4 of them always switching to “Occupied” when they enter, but always forget to switch back to “Vacant” when they exit.

If the room is actually occupied exactly 1/2 of the time, what is the probability the room is actually vacant when the sign reads “Vacant”?

This is the solution and I can't understand a few things:
This is a conditional probability problem:
P(vacant | sign reads “Vacant”) = P(vacant AND sign reads “Vacant”) / P(sign reads “Vacant”)
If the sign reads “Vacant”, one of these must be true:
The room is vacant AND the last employee who doesn’t ignore the sign was an employee that switches on both enter and exit (otherwise the sign would read “Occupied”).
Room is vacant $= 1/2$
Last employee who doesn’t ignore the sign was an employee that switches on both enter and exit $= (1/2) / (1/2 + 1/4) = 2/3$
Both are true $= 1/2 \times 2/3 = 1/3$
The room is occupied by an employee that ignores the sign AND the last employee who doesn’t ignore the sign was an employee that switches on both enter and exit.
Room is occupied by an employee that ignores the sign $= 1/2 \times 1/4 = 1/8$
Last employee who doesn’t ignore the sign was an employee that switches on both enter and exit $= (1/2) / (1/2 + 1/4) = 2/3$
Both are true $= 1/8 \times 2/3 = 1/12$
So the probability the room is actually “Vacant” $= (1/3) / (1/3 + 1/12) = 4/5$.

Both are true $= 1/2 \times 2/3 = 1/3$

I don't understand how they got this. The whole solution is quite hard to understand, possibly because I am not used to many problems like this.
Can someone please provide me with a comprehensible solution?

You need to totally describe all situations (status of the room+status of the signal), and probability for each combination. And only AFTER that, you can add  the information : 'the signal reads 'vacant', and focus on this subset.

Not sure the rules are clear.  If the sign says "Occupied", do people enter it anyway?  Are we to assume that the sign has no impact at all on who enters the room?

I think:  if you spell the rules out clearly and completely, the problem should be straight forward.  Without doing that, I fear it will come down to guesswork.

@lulu I found the question on tradinginterview.com and pasted it as it is. I suppose we could make that assumption.

To me, it seems that the vacant sign should then always be true ! The question seems to have meaning only if the sign read "occupied." None of them are changing "occupied" to "vacant" falsely.

I can imagine other assumptions.  The first and third types seem to respect the sign on some level...I figure those people would avoid a room marked as Occupied.  The middle type could plausibly ignore it.  Anyway, without explaining the rules, I don't see anyway to move forward on it.

@trueblueanil  Well, if there were only type II people, the sign would always read Vacant. Or if there were only types I and II.  Type III are the only ones that introduce error.

@lulu: True, but the error thry introduce is only to leave the sign "occupied" whrn it is actually vacant.

@trueblueanil  I think I am missing your point.  Say type III people are out of the picture.  Then the sign reads vacant if it is actually vacant or if it is occupied by a type II person.  It certainly doesn't have to be actually vacant.   If people respected the sign, of course, then as soon as a type III person used it once it would switch to Occupied and never leave that state as nobody else would ever go in.

@lulu: Oh, so you are assuming that a person won't go in if it is occupied ? OP hasn't really answered your initial query explicitly.

@trueblueanil  I;m not assuming anything!  Just pointing out that we need to clarify that issue.  To your earlier point, I am remarking that it is not true (under any assumption I can think of) that Vacant must imply Vacant, so to speak.  The room can be occupied by type II provided no type III person followed the most recent type I person.   If we label the types in order as $A,B,C$ and let $V$ refer to a vacant time, then the string $ABBVVVACAB$ would end in the room being occupied (by type II person $B$) but the sign will read Vacant.

That string would be perfectly valid under the assumption that nobody pays attention to the sign.


Your workplace has a phone room for employees to quietly make personal calls. The room has no windows, just a sign that can be switched from “Vacant” to “Occupied”. However, employees differ in how consistently they use the sign:

1/2 of them always switch to “Occupied” when they enter and “Vacant” when they exit.
1/4 of them ignore the sign altogether – the sign will always read the same before, during, and after their visit.
1/4 of them always switching to “Occupied” when they enter, but always forget to switch back to “Vacant” when they exit.

If the room is actually occupied exactly 1/2 of the time, what is the probability the room is actually vacant when the sign reads “Vacant”?

To attack the problem, I have made some simplifying assumptions.

There is only one phone in the room, so you can only have one person in the room at a time.  This assumption is suggested by the whole idea of using a sign that will read vacant or occupied.

Regardless of what the sign says, when a person wants to make a personal call, they will attempt to enter the room.  Then, if they see that someone else is using the room, they will leave the room without changing how the sign reads. 
That is, I am assuming that if a person unsuccessfully attempts to enter the room, then they never actually entered the room, so they never actually exited the room.


As has been indicated in the comments, since the problem is ambiguously worded, my assumptions may not represent the problem composer's intent.  However, I was unable to attack the problem without these assumptions, so I made the assumptions.
Let $~A~$ denote the event that the room is occupied, and that  the sign reads occupied. 
Let $~B~$ denote the event that the room is occupied, and that  the sign reads vacant. 
Let $~C~$ denote the event that the room is vacant, and that the sign reads occupied. 
Let $~D~$ denote the event that the room is vacant, and that the sign reads vacant.
Since the room is actually occupied $~(1/2)~$ of the time, you have that
$$p(A) + p(B) = \frac{1}{2} = p(C) + p(D).$$
The desired computation is
$$\frac{p(D)}{p(B) + p(D)}, \tag1 $$
so you have to use the problem's constraints to determine $~p(B)~$ and $~p(D).$

$50\%~$ of the time, the room will be occupied.  When this happens, what portion of this $50\%$ will represent that event $~B~$ occurred, rather than event $~A~?$
So, assume that the room is occupied.
$(1/2)~$ of the time, the sign will read occupied.
$(1/4)~$ of the time, the sign will be left as it was, after the last occupancy. 
After the last occupancy, when the room was then vacant, the probability that the sign would have read vacant is $~\dfrac{p(D)}{p(C) + p(D)} = 2p(D).$
A further $~(1/4)~$ of the time, the sign will read occupied.
So, under the assumption that the room is occupied, the probability that the sign will read vacant is
$$\frac{1}{4} \times 2p(D) = \frac{p(D)}{2}.$$
Therefore, the probability of event $~B~$ occurring is
$$p(B) = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{p(D)}{2} = \frac{p(D)}{4}. \tag2 $$

Now, the equation in (2) above can be fed into (1) above.
So, the desired computation is
$$\frac{p(D)}{p(B) + p(D)} $$
$$= \frac{p(D)}{\frac{p(D)}{4} + p(D)} = \frac{p(D)}{\frac{5}{4} \times p(D)} = \frac{4}{5}.$$

You can treat this as a Markov chain.  Using the same states and assumptions as user2661923:

A  denotes the state that the room is occupied, and that the sign reads occupied
B  denotes the state that the room is occupied, and that the sign reads vacant
C  denotes the state that the room is vacant, and that the sign reads occupied
D  denotes the state that the room is vacant, and that the sign reads vacant

you have the transition matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & \frac12 & \frac12 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\frac34 & \frac14 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
The stable distribution is $\left(\frac 6{14},\frac 1{14}, \frac 3{14}, \frac 4{14}\right)$
and this does not need to be adjusted for vacant/occupied times,
so the probability the room is vacant given that the sign reads vacant is $\frac{\frac 4{14}}{\frac 1{14}+\frac 4{14}}=\frac45$.
Similarly the probability the room is occupied given that the sign reads occupied is $\frac{\frac 6{14}}{\frac 6{14}+\frac 3{14}}=\frac23$.
